# Search sqlite records and go to specific activity Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I know this is a basic question, but I'm so confused what to do. I have hardcoded my first app. Below is what I've tried:

```
 String Search  = SearchAuto.getText().toString();

 if(SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Chowchow") || 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Chihuahua")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("German Shephered")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Beagle")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Shih tzu")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Siberian Husky")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Pug")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Poodle")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Pomeranian")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Labrador Retriever")){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Dogs.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(strDog, SearchAuto.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                startActivity(myIntent);
                SearchAuto.setText("");
            }
            else if(SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("American Shorthair") || 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Bengal")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Himalayan")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Maine Coon")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Manx")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Persian")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Ragdoll")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Russian Blue")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Siamese")|| 
                    SearchAuto.getText().toString().equals("Sphynx")){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Cats.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(strCat, SearchAuto.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                startActivity(myIntent);
                SearchAuto.setText("");
            }
```

But I want my data to be dynamic so I created a database to store my data.

Now my problem is how do I create a query/change the above code to satisfy my needs?

THis is what I've tried so far:

**DBHelper.class**

```
  public Cursor fetchbByAnimalType(String animalType, String breed) throws SQLException {

      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (animalType == null  ||  animalType.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_BREED },
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
          mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_BREED },
         KEY_ANIMALTYPE + " like '%" + animalType + "%' AND " + KEY_BREED + breed, null, null, null, null);
      }

      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      } 

      return mCursor;
}

public Cursor fetchbBreedByName(CharSequence breed) throws SQLException {

      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (breed == null  ||  breed.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_ANIMALTYPE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, 
               KEY_DIET, KEY_SHELTER, KEY_HYGIENE, KEY_MEDICATION, KEY_BREED },
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
          mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_ANIMALTYPE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, 
               KEY_DIET, KEY_SHELTER, KEY_HYGIENE, KEY_MEDICATION, KEY_BREED },
         KEY_BREED + " like '%" + breed + "%'", null, null, null, null);
      }

      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      } 

      return mCursor;
}
```

**Search.class**

```
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String Search  = SearchAuto.getText().toString();

            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchbBreedByName(Search);

            String strID, strBreed, strAnimalType;

            strID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            strBreed = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("breed"));
            strAnimalType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animaltype"));

            Log.d("Search", "Search for " + strBreed + " ID is " + strID);


            if(Search.equals(strBreed) || strAnimaltype){ <<---- I don't know what condition I have to put in here!!!!!! I need help
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Dogs.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra(strDog, Search);
                    startActivity(myIntent); 
            }

   }
```

I put an indicator to the line that I'm having an issue. Although I haven't run this, I know it will crash. Any ideas how to achieve what I want? I really need help in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do:

create two ArrayLists, say, DogsList and CatsList, and add the respective objects (to be specific, String) into it.

```
String[] DogsArray = new String {"Chihuahua", "", "", ...};
ArrayList<String> DogsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(DogsArray));

String[] CatsArray = new String {"American Shorthair", "", "", ...};
ArrayList<String> CatsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(CatsArray));
```

Then,

```
if(DogsList.contains(SearchAuto.getText().toString()))
{
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Dogs.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(strDog, SearchAuto.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                startActivity(myIntent);
}
else if(CatsList.contains(SearchAuto.getText().toString()))
{
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Cats.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(strCat, SearchAuto.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Hope this thing helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the SQLite is working, I guess since you already have `strBreed` and `strAnimalType`, you can put it like this

```
if(strAnimalType.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") { /* or the value to indicate cat */
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Cats.class);
    myIntent.putExtra(strCat, strBreed);
    startActivity(myIntent);
} else if(strAnimalType.equalsIgnoreCase("dog") { /* or the value to indicate dog */
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Dogs.class);
    myIntent.putExtra(strDog, strBreed);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: This is nice but what if the user adds another record? How will he be able to view that newly created record if the code is hardcoded?